# Relative SpaCy model import with variable name in YAML

Tags: python, yaml, rasa, rasa-core

I’m creating a pipeline to make it easy to train many bots. For this purpose I’ve tried to do add the following variable into my rasa `config.yml` pipeline:

```yaml
language: "../../language_models/${LANG_MODEL}"
recipe: default.v1
pipeline:
  - name: SpacyNLP
    model: "../../language_models/${LANG_MODEL}"
```

here, the SpacyNLP module would perform an import of a model saved to the local machine. This convention of variables is quite normal for YAML files as I’ve understood. Here `LANG_MODEL` is an environment variable (i.e. export `LANG_MODEL="en_core_web_lg"` is run beforehand). This does not work however... any suggestions? It’s curious because the following config works perfectly fine for me when I run my `endpoints.yml` file:

```yaml
tracker_store:
  type: mongod
  url: mongodb://${MONGO_IP}:${MONGO_PORT}/
  db: ${BOT_NAME}
  username: ${MONGO_USRN}
  password: ${MONGO_PW}
```

Thanks!

PS. Here is the specific error I get when I try to run `rasa train` with the `config.yml` file setup above:

```bash
2022-06-02 15:43:36 INFO     rasa.nlu.utils.spacy_utils  - Trying to load SpaCy model with name '../../language_models/${LANG_MODEL}'.
2022-06-02 15:43:36 ERROR    rasa.engine.graph  - Error initializing graph component for node provide_SpacyNLP0.
InvalidModelError: Please confirm that ../../language_models/${LANG_MODEL} is an available spaCy model. You need to download one upfront. For example:
python -m spacy download en_core_web_md
More information can be found on https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/components#spacynlp
```

It seems as though the environment variable is not inserted into the statement.

Comment: I don't know what `endpoints.yml` is, but spaCy's `project.yml` doesn't automatically resolve variables to the environment. You can pick specific env vars to use though, see here. https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/11135

Comment: `endpoints.yml` is related to a Rasa OpenSource (https://rasa.com/) project. Now that you mention it, it's not directly related to a SpaCy issue, so I've removed the `spacy` tag from the question.